# Is gradient of velocity an outer product?

Tags: tensor-products, mathematical-physics, tensors, fluid-dynamics

In outer product Wikipedia article we find this definition of outer product

[image]

But in strain-rate tensor Wikipedia article we find that gradient of velocity is

[image]

If I consider nabla as a "vector", as always we do, the two definition are different. There is a trasposition. What happened here?

Comment: In the first case the representation is chosen such that when the matrix $A$ acts on the vector $v$, it produces the vector $u$ multiplied by the norm of $v$ squared. On the other hand, if you start with a single vector (here the velocity $v$), it is standard to represent it as a column vector. The gradient acting on it therefore is represented in row form. So indeed, there is a difference !

Comment: It looks like you may have found a mistake. Later in the wiki article it says that the same matrix is equal to $(\nabla v)^T$.

Comment: Actually I find the speed gradient written that way in other sites and books as well. And it is a shame because the tensor calculus is already complicated enough not to complicate things further with not standardizing notations (maybe a bad habit that haunts physics more than mathematics). I have the impression that the vectors must "naturally" be written as column, and that the internal and external products must be profitably interpreted as products row by column into which the first and second vector is transposed respectively.